# How to set up TypeScript and SCSS as the default languages for script and style of Vue components with Vite?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, sass, vite

I have created a project with Vue 2.8 and Vite. To use TypeScript and SCSS I have to explicitly indicate it in every component:

`<script lang="ts">`

`<style scoped lang="scss">`

Given the project uses **Vite**, how do I set TypeScript as the default script language, and SCSS as the default schema for style?

Comment: AFAIK, you can't. You have to specify it everytime. But you can save time by create a snippet in your IDE to auto generate this for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can write your own snippet.

Assuming you are using vscode,
create a vue snippet like this:

```
{
  "vue-ts-sfc": {
    "prefix": "sfc",
    "body": [
      "<template>",
      "  <div class=\"container\">",
      "    <!-- content here -->",
      "  </div>",
      "</template>\n",
      "<script setup lang=\"ts\">",
      "</script>\n",
      "<style lang=\"scss\" scoped>",
      ".container {",
      "  box-sizing: border-box;",
      "}",
      "</style>"
    }
}
```

then you got
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but your answer doesn't provide an actual answer to the question.